# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139) Andrioid Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried running an app on my AVD in Android Studio and the error message
"Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)" pops up..

I tried cold booting the AVD and I also tried running the app on my android device..but it doesn't still run
I saw something online which lead me to the qemu folder on my PC.I tried running the qemu-system-i386.exe but it pops up the error message
"The procedure entry point _ZN10SvgWidget4loadERK7QString could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Svg.dll"..

Answer (score 0):

Try to wipe your emulator data from AVD Manager then use cold boot to start it.
That worked for me!